# Como fazer um beginTransaction no Zend framework?

Tags: php, zend, zend-framework-2

```html
 public function alterar($objDadosSindicato)
    {    
  $this->conexao->beginTransaction();

        try
        {
        $alterouSindicato = $this->repositorioDadosSindicato->alterar($objDadosSindicato);
        
        /** Filiação / Desfiliação */
        $this->verificarFiliacaoDesfiliacao($objDadosSindicato->dataFiliacao, $objDadosSindicato->objFiliacaoDesfiliacao);
        
        /** Carteirinha */
        $this->verificaSituacaoCarteirinha($objDadosSindicato->objCarteirinha);
        
        /** Urna */
        $this->verificaSituacaoUrna($objDadosSindicato->objUrna);
       
        /** Pontuação */
        $this->verificaSituacaoPontuacao($objDadosSindicato->objPontuacao);
   
        /** Log */            
  LogFW::salvar(__METHOD__, $objDadosSindicato->idDadosSindicato, $objDadosSindicato);
        
        if($objDadosSindicato->objFiliacaoDesfiliacao->idMotivoDesfiliacao == 0 && $objDadosSindicato->objFiliacaoDesfiliacao->data == null){
   $this->validarSituacaoEnvioSiape($objDadosSindicato);
  }else{
   $this->alterarFiliadoSiapeExclusao($objDadosSindicato->objFiliacaoDesfiliacao);
  }
        $this->conexao->commit();
        return $alterouSindicato;
  
   }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->conexao->rollback();
        }
    }
```

Estou fazendo uma exceção com begin no framework zend, mas o mesmo sempre entra na exceção não executando a função desejada.

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim utilizar gerenciador transações no Zend. Para isso, faça dessa forma:

```
// Chamar adaptador que obterá gerenciador de transações
$db_adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

// Para iniciar transação
$db_adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

// Para commitar transação
$db_adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->commit();

// Para voltar transação
$db_adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->rollback();
```